# Generate all adjacency matrices of size $n=4$ s.t. $a_{ij}\neq a_{ij}$ and $a_{ii}==0$

Tags: list-manipulation, graphs-and-networks, conditional

I want to generate a list of adjacency matrices of size $n=4$ s.t.

1. The diagonal is zero: $a_{ii}=0$ for all $i\in\lbrace 1,2,...,n\rbrace$
2. There are no 2-cyles, i.e. if $a_{ij}==1$, then $a_{ji}==0$ for $i,j\in\lbrace 1,2,...,n\rbrace$

So far, I have only achieved the first part with

```
adjlist = DeleteDuplicates[ReplacePart[Tuples[{0, 1}, {n, n}], {a_, i_, i_} -> 0]]
```

How can I achieve the second part? I have tried combinations of `/;` and `Replace part` without success.

**Edit:** I have achieved the second part with the following loop

```
For[t = 1, t <= Length[networks], t++,
  For[i = 1, i <= n, i++,
   (*Print["entered loop i"];*)
   For[j = 1, j <= i, j++,
    (*Print["entered loop j"]*)
    
    If[And[networks[[t, i, j]] == 1, networks[[t, j, i]] == 1],
     (*Print["Entered loop ij"];*)
     
     networks = ReplacePart[networks, {t, i, j} -> 0];
     networks = ReplacePart[networks, {t, j, i} -> 0];
     ]]]];
```

Is there a better (more efficient) way to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Similar to @lericr's solution, but using `BacktrackSearch` to avoid using `Tuples` and discarding, which becomes a memory hog for larger `n`

```
tomtx[list_, n_] := ArrayReshape[list, {n, n}]
valid[list_, n_] := FreeQ[# + Transpose[#], 2] &@tomtx[list, n]
generate[n_, maxMatrices_] := tomtx[#, n] & /@
   ResourceFunction["BacktrackSearch"][Array[{0, 1} &, n*n],
    valid[PadRight[#, n*n], n] &,
    valid[#, n] &
    , maxMatrices];

generate[4, 20]

Length[generate[4, All]]
(* 729 *)
```

OEIS confirms 729 is correct in sequence [A047656](https://oeis.org/A047656):

> a(n) = 3^((n^2-n)/2).
>
> 1, 1, 3, 27, 729, 59049, ...
>
> The number of n X n binary matrices A that have a(i,j)=0 whenever a(j,i)=1 for i!=j and zeros on the diagonal. We need only consider the (n^2-n)/2 non-diagonal entry pairs <a(i,j), a(j,i)>. Since each pair is of the form <0,0>, <0,1>, or <1,0>, a(n) = 3^((n^2-n)/2). - Dennis P. Walsh, Apr 03 2014

Comment: nice. yeah, I was worried that the follow up would be to increase the size of the matrix.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming I've understood (please correct if I'm wrong), something along these lines might work.

Start by generating all of the matrices with 0|1 entries. These are 4x4, so we could just generate them all (2^16 of them), but we know we only need 2^12 since the diagonals are constrained to be all 0. So, we could generate all 12-tuples and insert the diagonals:

```
allNarrowArrays = Tuples[{0, 1}, 12];
ToMatrix[list_List] := 
  ArrayReshape[Riffle[list, 0, {1, -1, 5}], {4, 4}] /; 12 == Length[list];
allZeroDiagonalMatrices = ToMatrix /@ allNarrowArrays;
```

If there were a 2-cycle, then a[[i,j]] == a[[j,i]] == 1. If we were to add a matrix with its transpose, then we'd get 2s when a 2 cycle exists. So, we'll create a filter that checks this:

```
TwoCycleFreeQ[matrix_?MatrixQ] := 
  FreeQ[matrix + Transpose[matrix], 2] /; {4, 4} == Dimensions[matrix];
cycleFree = Select[allZeroDiagonalMatrices, TwoCycleFreeQ];
Length@cycleFree
```

`729`

Off the top of my head, I'm not sure how to check that this is correct in theory. A few random samples suggest that this works.

The conditional checks on the shape of the inputs aren't strictly necessary--I was just trying to be very explicit.

**UPDATE**

Based on @flinty's info, another way we could generate the matrices directly (i.e. without overgenerating and filtering) would be like this:

```
MakeLowerTriangular[n_Integer?Positive][list_] := 
  PadRight[TakeList[list, Range[0, n - 1]], {n, n}];
MakeUpperTriangular[n_Integer?Positive][list_] := 
  Transpose[MakeLowerTriangular[n][list]];
MatrixFromSpec[n_Integer?Positive][pairs : {{_, _} ...}] :=
  With[
    {diagSpecs = Transpose[pairs]},
    MakeLowerTriangular[n][diagSpecs[[1]]] + 
    MakeUpperTriangular[n][diagSpecs[[2]]]];
AdjMatsWithout1Or1Cycles[n_Integer?Positive] :=
  MatrixFromSpec[n] /@ Tuples[{{0, 1}, {1, 0}, {0, 0}}, (n - 1) n/2];
theMatrices = AdjMatsWithout1Or1Cycles[4]; Length@theMatrices
```

`729`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @lericr! Even though I accepted @flinty's answer, yours taught me some new tools I had not used before.